# SafeAreaView is not working inside modal screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist, react-native-modal

I have a modal screen (`presentation: 'modal'`) and inside it I have a scrollable `FlatList`. The problem is that I cannot achieve spacing at the bottom together with transparent bottom safe area. I use `SafeAreaView` from `react-native-safe-area-context`.

I have tried many solutions and non actually worked. So far I have tried:

1. Wrapping screen content with `SafeAreaView`;
2. Wrapping FlatList with `SafeAreaView`;
3. Adding `style={ { paddingBottom: 50 } }` to FlatList;
4. Adding `contentContainerStyle={ { paddingBottom: 50 } }` to FlatList;
5. Adding `ListFooterComponent={ <SafeAreaView edges={ ['bottom'] } forceInset={ { bottom: 'always' } } /> }` to FlatList;
6. Also tried using ScrollView instead of FlatList.

**Screenshots:**

I either have a scrollbar to the bottom of the screen, but listing has correct spacing:
[image]

**OR**

have a margin at the bottom and then the scrollbar looks good (it scrolls to the red line):
[image]

If I compare it to native iOS applications, they behave exactly how I want- scrollbar is scrolling to the safe area and bottom are is transparent when I scroll:
[image]

Screen component:

```js
return (
        <SafeAreaView forceInset={ { top: 'never', bottom: 'always' } }>
            <View style={ styles.container }>
                <FlatList
                    style={ { marginBottom: 0 } }
                    // showsVerticalScrollIndicator={ false }
                    // contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
                    numColumns={ 4 }
                    // ListFooterComponent={ <SafeAreaView edges={ ['bottom'] } mode="margin" forceInset={ { bottom: 'always' } } /> }
                    // contentInset={ { bottom: 1 } }
                    // contentContainerStyle={ [{paddingBottom: 30 }] }
                    data={ [] }
                    renderItem={ ({ item }) => {
                        return renderCategory(item);
                    } }
                />

            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
```

Navigator component:

```js
return (
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="DashboardStack">
            <Stack.Group screenOptions={ {
                headerLargeTitle: false,
                headerShown: true,
                headerShadowVisible: false,
                presentation: 'modal'
            } }>
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="CategoryModal"
                    component={ CategoryModal }
                    options={ {
                        title: 'Categories',
                        contentStyle: {
                            backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
                        }
                    } }
                />
            </Stack.Group>
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
```

Comment: you need to have SafeAreaProvider somewhere above in the tree https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context#safeareaprovider